# python gzip decompress file

Tags: python, compression, gzip

I am trying to decompress a file using it's location:

```
gzip.decompress(input_path)
```

where input path is /media/uploads/dino_test.msh_b1R1dcs.gz

I get the following error:

```
File "/usr/lib64/python3.6/gzip.py", line 531, in decompress
with GzipFile(fileobj=io.BytesIO(data)) as f:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'
```

I understand decompress is expecting a file and not the path. How do I decompress a file knowing the location? The file is uploaded and put into the location by a python scrip running in the backend.

Comment: Maybe try `gzip.open(input_path)`

Answer (score 0):

```
gz_files = [file for file in os.listdir(input_path) if file.endswith('.gz')]
```

If you are sure you have only one file then

```
gzip.decompress(gz_files[0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Try with below code, decompress needed a file object.

```
with open(input_path) as fp:
   gzip.decompress(fp)
```